# Less robotic voice from gTTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, voice-recognition, gtts

I created a basic virtual assistant. It works, but it just sounds terrible, like a robotic voice you get from a scam call. The package I'm using for this is gTTS, which works great, but it doesn't have a nice sounding voice. Is there anything I can do to change that?

Code from my script:

```
tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang="en")
r = random.randint(1, 10000000)
audio_file = "audio-" + str(r) + ".mp3"
tts.save(audio_file)
playsound.playsound(audio_file)
print(audio_string)
os.remove(audio_file)
```

I've already tried `en-us` or `en-uk` but it doesn't work. The voice is still the same. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: See [Localized ‘accents’](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#localized-accents) though some of them sound the same, e.g., US and Canada sound the same but Australian sounds different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyttsx3 module

```
import pyttsx3

#Starting microsoft speech api sapi5
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')#fetching different voices from the system
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)#setting voice properties
engine.setProperty('rate', 130)#sets speed of speech

#enables speech
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

You can replace 1 by 0 for a male voice in the engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id) statement